# Excel VBA - Ckeck if cell contains a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following script to add checkboxes to a range of cells. I would like to enhance this by checking if the cell already contains a checkbox and if it does then do not add a new checkbox in the cell, ie only add a check box to a cell in the range if it does not already contain a checkbox.

```
    LRow = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For cell = 10 To LRow
        CLeft = Cells(cell, "R").Left
        CTop = Cells(cell, "R").Top
        CHeight = Cells(cell, "R").Height
        CWidth = Cells(cell, "R").Width
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select
        With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
Next cell
```

Comment: Create and array of `Range`, cycle through all checkboxes on your sheet and add their `TopLeftCell` property to that array. Then you can check if a given cell is within that array, you know it contains a checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function to check if a range contains a checkbox:

```
Public Function HasCheckbox(rng As Range) As Boolean
    For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If Not Application.Intersect(rng, CB.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            HasCheckbox = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next CB
    HasCheckbox = False
End Function
```