# Loop rows of column until empty in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a column "N" that contains 30 rows with checkbox inside each one

in vba i want to make a loop that stops at the empty cell, means row 31 , i tried this way :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Range("N9").Select
 
 Do

 If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Call do_OM 
 
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 
  
 
 Loop while ActiveCell.value = "" 


 


End Sub
```

this loop works for only one row , which means a cell with checkbox is an empty cell , while what i want is to stop at cell with no checkbox .. what to do ?

+

How to say " If CheckBox(row number).Value = True ? "

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your selection in this case doesn't actually do anything related to the checkboxes. You are always checking the value of specifically `CheckBox1` no matter what cells you are selecting.

Comment: so what to do to verify if there is no more checkBox in it ?

Comment: CheckBoxes are `Shapes` and shapes are on a distinct UI layer that is superimposed over the worksheet grid. The location of a shape is defined by the distance (in points) of its top left corner from the top left corner of the Excel screen so that the point (0, 0) is equal to the top left corner of cell A1. Since cells and shapes are on different layers no cell can be in a shape and no shape can be in a cell. You can position several shapes at the same coordinates but you couldn't see them all. You can use the Z-Order to determine which one should be "on top".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
**This part will iterate through the non-Active X checkboxes**

Since the checkbox isn't tied to the sheet, there isn't really a way to say `CheckBox(row number)`. Also makes sense because there could be multiple boxes on one row.
If the names of the checkboxes align with the row number, however, then you can iterate through them. Well, you can iterate through them anyway, but yeah.

You could do something like:

```
For i = 1 To 30
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(i).Value
Next i
```

or

```
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    chk.Value
Next chk
```

To iterate through the boxes. Second one would obviously go through the entire sheet.
I don't think you can check a cell for a box, but you can check what cell the box is in, by using `.TopLeftCell.Row` which should return the row of the top left corner of the object. Then you could cross-reference that (and perhaps `.TopLeftCell.Column`) with your range using `Intersect`.

[Excel VBA - Ckeck if cell contains a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921758/excel-vba-ckeck-if-cell-contains-a-checkbox) Might be of interest. But as I said, it's not really checking if a cell has a check box, it's going through all the checkboxes and checking if any of them are in the cell, using Intersect as I suggested. You can argue that the end result is the same however.

*Edit* For the comment: **This is for ACTIVE X Boxes**

```
Dim nm As Object
Set nm = ActiveSheet.CheckBox1
nm.TopLeftCell.Row

'Iteration
For Each nm In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(nm.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        debug.print nm.TopLeftCell.row
        If nm.Object.Value = True Then ' do stuff
    End If
Next nm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  ,i'll try this one, Can you please tell me for exemple i have Dim nm As String where nm contains the name of a checkBox (chekbox1 or checkbox2 ..)  , why i  can't  apply this line of code : row_se = nm & TopLeftCell.Row  i get an error , i want to get something like ( if nm = checkbox3) row_se = checkbox3.TopLeftCell.Row

Comment: Excel is being picky with using strings and names. Dim nm as an object, and it should work, see the edit.

Comment: I was getting weird results with my iterations, and I realized they iterate the form control checkboxes, not the active x ones.

Comment: I still get some errors , ah really, becaus i'm using the active x ones, and i really don't know the difference between the 2 types despite the active x have the open  ' see the code '

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that got me a bit confused as well. First part should work on the others, and the last part should be for Active X.

Answer (score 1):

### ActiveX Checkboxes

- Remove, replace or out-comment the `Debug.Print` lines with something you need e.g. `do_OM` (`Call` is considered deprecated).
- Note this: `ole.Name`, but `ole.Object.Value`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckBoxExample()
    Dim ole As OLEObject
    For Each ole In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print ole.Name, ole.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0), _
                ole.BottomRightCell.Address(0, 0)
            If ole.Object.Value = True Then
                'do_OM
                Debug.Print "Check Box '" & ole.Name & "' is ticked."
            Else
                Debug.Print "Check Box '" & ole.Name & "' is not ticked."
            End If
        End If
    Next ole
End Sub

Sub CheckBoxExample2()
    Dim ole As OLEObject
    For Each ole In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            Debug.Print ole.Name, ole.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0), _
                ole.BottomRightCell.Address(0, 0)
            With ole.Object
                Debug.Print .Caption, .Value
            End With
        End If
    Next ole
End Sub
```